# How to execute the same query across multiple google cloud projets and save the result in same table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 100 projects GCP , in each GCP project I have a dataset that contains multiple tables.
Tables have the same name and schema across different project.

I want to run a query that create a table from the 100 projects, this query is a union all of a select from each project.

exemple:

```
   select a, b, c, d
   from proj1.dataset1.table
   union all 
   select a, b, c, d
   from proj2.dataset1.table
   .
   .
   .
```

first question: it's recommended to copy input tables in my project then I execute my query ?
second question: can I configure my query to use wildcard in project name and dataset name (not in table name) ?

Thanks.

Comment: This just works, just try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for First Question: No you don't need to copy input tables to your project.

Answer for Second Question: No, wildcard works only in table names.

Look for [UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#sql) in BigQuery this may leads you to a solution.

For this kind of problem I use [Dataform](https://cloud.google.com/dataform) to build the SQL Query.